# Adding index from activity_main Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created button in activity_main.xml and make an index as but1.
After it I go to MainActivity.kt and try to use this index for example:

[image]

Should I add this but1 somewhere else?

Comment: I think you mean `id`, not "index". Put the cursor on it and press Alt+Enter to see if it suggest the import to add to your file.

Comment: <Button id:"@+id/but1"> and in main activity -> val but : Button = findViewByid(R.id.but1)